# ProvisionException in Controller when using implicit Writes

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play Framework 2.5 and I got the exception when trying to run the application.

> ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: 1)
>   Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   controllers.MyController.(MyController.scala:22)
>   while locating controllers.MyControllerfor parameter 2 at
>   router.Routes.(Routes.scala:43) while locating router.Routes
>   while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider while locating
>   play.api.routing.Router for parameter 0 at
>   play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
>   while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler while
>   locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler for parameter 4 at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.(Application.scala:221) at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221) while
>   locating play.api.DefaultApplication while locating
>   play.api.Application

That is the signature of my controller class

```
class MyShopController @Inject()(system: ActorSystem, val messagesApi: MessagesApi)(implicit context: ExecutionContext) extends Controller with I18nSupport {
...
}
```

And I got a simple model in which I created nested implicit writes for json conversion.  That is what seems to be the problem.

```
object MyShop extends MyShopTrait {
    case class Consumer(name: String)
    case class Producer(name: String)
    case class ProducerRow(producer: Producer, consumers: List[Consumer])

    implicit val writesConsumer: Writes[Consumer] = (
          (JsPath \ "name").write[String]
      )(unlift(Consumer.unapply))

      implicit val writesProducer: Writes[Producer] = (
        (JsPath \ "name").write[String]
      )(unlift(Producer.unapply))

    implicit val writesProducerRow: Writes[ProducerRow] = (
        (JsPath \ "producer").write[Producer] and
        (JsPath \ "consumers").write[List[Consumer]]
      )(unlift(ProducerRow.unapply))

    val producerRows = List[ProducerRow](
        ProducerRow(Producer("Producer1"), List(Consumer("Consumer1"), Consumer( "Consumer2"))),
        ProducerRow(Producer("Producer2"), List(Consumer("Consumer3"), Consumer("Consumer4")))
      )
      val json = Json.toJson(producerRows)
}
```

When I comment the last 5 lines of code :

```
val producerRows = List[ProducerRow](
  ProducerRow(Producer("Producer1"), List(Consumer("Consumer1"), Consumer( "Consumer2"))),
  ProducerRow(Producer("Producer2"), List(Consumer("Consumer3"), Consumer("Consumer4")))
)
val json = Json.toJson(producerRows)
```

I don't have the exception

Comment: If you remove (implicit context: ExecutionContext), does it work ? You can use dependency injection to get ExecutionContext. My guess is that Guice doesn't have implicit execution context when it calls the class constructor.

Comment: It didn't work after I remove the implicit context but I could what was my error and could fix it.  Thanks.